# Ajax call executing error function even server call success in blackberry isuue

Tags: jquery, blackberry

The following piece of codes work fine in android,ios.But in blackberry request is going to server and server is responding . But Ajax fires error function with status=0,readystate=0 and Network err:XMLHttpRequestException 101.
 How to resolve this issue?

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "http://192.168.1.190:8181/Asf/User/myService",                                     
    type : "POST",
    //cache : false,
    crossDomain:true,
    data : pjsonstring,
    //contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout : 50000,
    success : function (json1) {
    alert("in success");
        fnsetjson(json1);
    },
    error : function (xhr , textStatus , errorThrown) {
        alert("Error- Status: " + textStatus + " xhr Status: " + xhr.status + " xhr Response Text:" + xhr.responseText);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ajax` calls using `jQuery` WILL NOT work in any Black Berry phones having OS version 5.0.

Try using plain `XmlHTTPRequest object (XHR)` for your `AJAX calls` if your targeted BB OS is 5.0.

Comment: try it using normal `XmlHTTPRequest object` in BB

Comment: xhr.statusText == "error"
xhr.readyState == 0
xhr.status == 0
xhr.responseText == undefined it is printing.